# Attempt to remove row from p:dataTable only removes last row instead of current row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I want users to be able to add and remove rows with `p:inputText` in a `p:dataTable`, once the user is ready, then will submit and save the information.

My code has no problem adding and saving. the problem is when user wants to remove those rows, it just removes the last added inputText regardless of which "delete" button you press.

form.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="+" 
                 action="#{quoteRequestForm.addQuotation}" 
                 immediate="true" 
                 update="supplier_form"
                 />
        <p:dataTable border="0" 
                     value="#{quoteRequestForm.quotations}" 
                     var="p"
                     rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                     emptyMessage="#{text['quoteRequest.noSupplier']}" 
                     id="supplier_form"
                     >
            <p:column>
                 <h:inputText id="vendorName" 
                              value="#{p.vendorName}" 
                              styleClass="form-control" 
                              required="true" maxlength="255"
                              />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
              <p:commandButton value="remove" 
                               action="#{quoteRequestForm.removeElement(p)}"
                               update="supplier_form" 
                               immediate="true"
                               />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

managed bean:

```
@Component("quoteRequestForm")
@ViewScoped
public class QuoteRequestForm extends BasePage implements Serializable {
   private List<Quotation> quotations = new ArrayList<Quotation>();
....
...
 public void addQuotation(){
        Quotation q = new Quotation();
        q.setSupplier(supplierList.get(0));
        quotations.add(q);
    }


    public void removeElement(Quotation q){
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Quotation supplier to delete: " + q.getVendorName());
        }
        this.quotations.remove(q);
    }

...
}
```

the debug also shows "q.getVendorName() = null" in the removeElement function

what am I missing to make this work as user expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine like this (different variable names but same principle):

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:commandButton value="+" action="#{testMB.addItem}" 
        immediate="true" update="tableId"/>
    <p:dataTable border="0" value="#{testMB.problemList}" var="p"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex" id="tableId">
        <p:column>
             <h:inputText id="description" value="#{p.description}"
                 required="#{param['formId:save']!=null}" maxlength="255"/>
        </p:column>
         <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="remove" actionListener="#{testMB.removeItem(p)}" update="tableId"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton id="save" value="Save"
        action="#{testMB.saveItems}" update="tableId"/>
</h:form>
```

if you use `process="@this"`, whenever you want to delete a row, you cannot preserve the input values you have already set, all the inputText values will be reset, which we definitely don't want. on the other hand, if you don't use `process="@this"` as in this code and at least one of the inputText values is empty, validation fails because of `required="true"` and you are not able to delete any row without filling all inputTexts. so, we do the validation only when the save button is pressed, as in `required="#{param['formId:save']!=null}"`.

Comment: But if I don's use immediate the form will be validated before add a inputText each time :/

Comment: Hi, I tried and worked, thanks. but anyway would mind to explain me why you changed your answer and decided not to use process=@this?

Comment: oh, sorry about not being descriptive enough. :) i added the explanation to the answer.